# Cannot find the height of an embedded PDF in an iframe in Electron app? ScrollHeight has wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, electron

I have a dynamic iframe that has changing PDFs being embedded based on what the user uploads. I need to dynamically change the height of these iframes based on the height of its contents in order to get rid of the iframe scrollbar. The scrollHeight is always the same as the height of the iframe element though regardless how long the document (how long the scrollbar) is. My app has two scrollbars (1 for whole app and 1 for iframe).

When I try and look at the scrollHeight, I get the wrong value.

```
>    $('#iframepdf')[0].contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight
<    4996
>    $('#iframepdf')[0].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight
<    0
```

I set the CSS for the iframe to 5000px and the scrollHeight is based off that instead of what the iframe's scrollbar actually is.

I am also using bootstrap.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pdfRow" class="row">
    <div id="selectionMarquee"></div>
    <div id="pdfCols" class="col-md-12">
        <iframe id="iframepdf" scrolling="no" src="" frameborder="0" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
    </div>>
</div>
```

This is how I dynamically change the iframe src:

```
<script>
    $('#file').on('change',function()
    {   
        var file_path = document.getElementById("file").files[0].path
        var mod_file_path = file_path + '#zoom=100'
        $("#iframepdf").attr('src', mod_file_path)
        $('#pdfRow').show()
    });
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#pdfRow{
    /* position:relative; */
    height: 5000px;
    width: 100%;
    /* padding-bottom: 56.25%; */
}

#pdfCols{
    width:100%!important;
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    height: 100%;
    /* height:1000px; */
}

#iframepdf{
    /* display: block; */
    z-index:-1;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    /* height:100%; */
    height:5000px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
}
```

I've tried changing the CSS quite a bit but the scrollHeight never seems to reflect what is actually in the iframe. Maybe it has something to do with Electron?